# Cython support in Vim's taglist?

Tags: vim, cython, taglist

I was wondering if it is possible to make vim's taglist to show cython source code information.

It seems ctag already supports cython, but Tlist does not show any information of opened cython file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. The following one liner in .vimrc file made it work:

```
let tlist_pyrex_settings='python;c:classe;m:memder;f:function'
```